# ovs2.6: could not create netdev dpdk1 of unknown type dpdk

Tags: installation, openvswitch, dpdk

I am trying to setup OVS2.6 with DPDK16.07. I am following INSTALL.DPDK.md instructions that came under [openvswitch-2.6.0.tar.gz](http://openvswitch.org/releases/openvswitch-2.6.0.tar.gz). Getting following warning message in ovs-vswitchd.log:

00034|netdev|WARN|could not create netdev dpdk1 of unknown type dpdk
00035|bridge|WARN|could not open network device dpdk1 (Address family not supported by protocol)

Googling little bit shows this issue is faced by earlier ovs version as well, but I didn't find any satisfactory solution.

Any idea what could be rootcause, and how to fix it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

All ports that are to be used by Open vSwitch must be bound to the uio_pci_generic, igb_uio or vfio-pci module before the application is run. Any network ports under Linux control will be ignored by OvS or any DPDK application.

Please check the output of $DPDK_DIR/tools/dpdk-devbind.py scripts with -s parameter. You must see some ports in "Network devices using DPDK-compatible driver" section like below;

```
$/dpdk-stable-16.07.2/tools$ ./dpdk-devbind.py -s
Network devices using DPDK-compatible driver
============================================
0000:05:00.0 '82571EB Gigabit Ethernet Controller (Copper)' drv=igb_uio unused=e1000e
0000:05:00.1 '82571EB Gigabit Ethernet Controller (Copper)' drv=igb_uio unused=e1000e
```

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue as well, and by checking the code I found that before starting ovs-vswitchd, we should use the command below, to initialize dpdk.

ovs-vsctl --no-wait set Open_vSwitch . other_config:dpdk-init=true